# Can not use PrimeNG in Angular CLI

Tags: angularjs, typescript, primeng

I try to use the PrimeNG in angular CLI but It doesn't work @@!

Component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ToolbarModule } from 'primeng/primeng';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-marketing-menu-bar',
  templateUrl: './marketing-menu-bar.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./marketing-menu-bar.component.css']
})
export class MarketingMenuBarComponent implements OnInit {
constructor() { }
ngOnInit() {
}
}
```

Here is the Component.html

```
<p-toolbar>  
<div class="ui-toolbar-group-right">
    <button pButton type="button" icon="fa-search"></button>
    <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
    <button pButton type="button" icon="fa-refresh"></button>
    <button pButton type="button" icon="fa-trash"></button>
</div>
```

After I run ng serve:

> Unhandled Promise rejection: Template parse errors:
>   'p-toolbar' is not a known element:
>   1. If 'p-toolbar' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
>   2. If 'p-toolbar' is a Web Component then add "CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA" to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message. ("[ERROR ->]
>       
>            ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: SyntaxError {_nativeError: Error: Template parse errors:
>   'p-toolbar' is not a known element:
>   1. If 'p-toolbar' is an Angular co…} Error: Template parse errors:
>   'p-toolbar' is not a known element:
>   1. If 'p-toolbar' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
>   2. If 'p-toolbar' is a Web Component then add "CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA" to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message. ("[ERROR ->]

Answer (score 2):

Did you import `ToolbarModule` inside your app.module.ts ?

```
import { ToolbarModule } from 'primeng/toolbar';
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message tells you what needs to be done. In the module which declares your component, add `CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA` to your imports, eg:

```
import { NgModule, CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA } from '@angular/core';
```

(You will already be importing `NgModule` from `@angular/core`, so just add the new import to this line, separated by a comma.)

Then add the following line somewhere within the `@NgModule` decorator:

```
schemas: [ CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA ]
```